# Prism, IConfirmNavigationRequest, InteractionRequest and Async

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-5

I have an issue, i coded my view, viewmodel creation into the ModuleInit.Initialize method

```
this.container.RegisterType<IControlPanel, ViewModels.SeveritiesViewModel>("SeveritiesViewModel");
this.container.RegisterType<object, Views.SeveritiesView>("SeveritiesView", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IControlPanel>("SeveritiesViewModel")));
```

SeveritiesVeiwModel inherits from ViewModelBase

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, IControlPanel, INavigationAware, IConfirmNavigationRequest
```

Constructor for ViewModelBase calls two virtual methods. Initialize and GetData. 
GetData performs some data access methods using async await.

so the problem i have is Prism constructs my SeveritiesViewModel, the GetData method runs, and throws and exception which i catch. i would then like to display a dialog using the InteractionRequest, however the view.DataContext has not yet be set, hence no bindings or Interaction.Triggers to receive the InteractionRequest.

so i thought i should look into RegionManager.RequestNaviagte using a callback. i thought since all my viewmodels implement IConfirmNavigationRequest i could return false in the NavigationResult from the View/viewmodel being injected. however ConfirmNavigationRequest is never called. this is wpf not silverlight?

so how do i work this extremely decoupled application. do i need to implement some type of shared service? 
I guess i am going to need to store exceptions until the view has finished binding with the viewmodel, perhaps implement my own interface with a method to check an exceptions collection and in the view call the interface method? 
why is ConfirmNavigationRequest never called?

InteractionRequest work great after the DataContext is set, but before; i'm at a loss.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Thanks 
Gary

here is some code.

toolbar button command click runs the following.

```
this.regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "SeveritiesView");
```

here is the code behind for the view.

```
public partial class SeveritiesView : UserControl, IApplicationView
{
    public SeveritiesView(IControlPanel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    public string ViewName
    {
        get { return "SeveritiesView"; }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.

```
        protected ViewModelBase(bool initializeDB = true) 
    {
        notifications = new List<NotificationWindowNotification>();
        this.uiFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        NotificationRequest = new InteractionRequest<NotificationWindowNotification>();
        ConfirmationRequest = new InteractionRequest<ConfirmationWindowNotification>();
        if (initializeDB)
        {
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = EventLogAnalysis.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
            db = new ServerEventLogEntities(entityBuilder.ToString());
        }
        ThrobberVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        Initialize();
        GetData();
    }
```

SeveritiesViewModel.

```
 public SeveritiesViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : base()
    {
        try
        {
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddSeverity>().Subscribe(AddSeverity);
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<DeleteSeverity>().Subscribe(DeleteSeverity);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                 uiFactory.StartNew(() =>
                NotificationRequest.Raise(new NotificationWindowNotification()
                {
                    Title = string.Format("Error during {0}.{1}"
                        , ModuleName, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name),
                    Content = string.Format("{0}", e.Message)
                })
            ).Wait();
        }

    }

protected async override void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            tasks.Add(GetEventFilterSeverities());

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                ThrobberVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<RecordStatusEvent>().Publish(new RecordStatusMessage() { CanAdd = true, CanDelete =(currentEventFilterSeverity != null), IsClosing = false });
            }
            , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           notifications.Add(new NotificationWindowNotification()
                {
                    Title = string.Format("Error during {0}.{1}"
                        , ModuleName, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name),
                    Content = string.Format("{0}", e.Message)
                });
        }

    }

protected async Task GetEventFilterSeverities()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("My exception");
            ObservableCollection<EventFilterSeverity> _eventFilterSeverities = new ObservableCollection<EventFilterSeverity>();
            var eventFilterSeverities = await (from sg in db.EventFilterSeverities
                                        orderby sg.EventFilterSeverityID
                                        select sg).ToListAsync();
            foreach (EventFilterSeverity efs in eventFilterSeverities)
                _eventFilterSeverities.Add(efs);
            EventFilterSeverities = _eventFilterSeverities;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            notifications.Add(new NotificationWindowNotification()
                {
                    Title = string.Format("Error during {0}.{1}"
                        , ModuleName, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name),
                    Content = string.Format("{0}", e.Message)
                });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two fairly easy solutions;

1. Do not start data access until the Shell has been displayed and interactions are possible
2. Catch the exception and immediatly `await` on a `Task` that completes when the interaction request becomes available. Is this when the navigation completes? This effectively queues the interaction for when it can be displayed.

Comment: So how would i do (2)?

Comment: I have a toolbar with commands bound to a toolbarviewmodel. under SeveritiesClick i call `code`RegionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "SeveritiesView"); which constructs the view and model and puts these in the content region. protected async Task GetEventFilterSeverities() throws and exception which i catch in the surrounding Try. where do I "await on a task that completes when the interaction request becomes available"

Comment: Thst really depends on how you are implementing the interfaces. Can you post more code? Perhaps a project that I can run?

Comment: I though maybe the GetData continuation might work since i instruct the task to continuewith using FromCurrentSynchronizationContext

Comment: Well one way i got this to work was. catch exceptions and add to a NaviagationParameters dictionary, when OnNavigatedTo is called push them into the navigationContext.Parameters. then during the  regionmanager.requestNavigate callback iterate the parameter raising notifications. Not much of a fan of this though. I think i am going to explore the StateManager flipping between Unavailable and Available.

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising.
in the view

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Raised" SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest}">
        <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
            <dialogs:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="DisplayPreBoundExceptions"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the ViewModelBase

```
        public void DisplayPreBoundExceptions()
    {
        notifications.ForEach((t) => NotificationRequest.Raise(t));
        notifications.Clear();
    }
```